# Preserve list of lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, loops

I'm trying to fetch some data from a large string. I want to `split` a `string` to smaller `strings`  and save it to a `list`. After that I want to loop every string in that list and `split` it again on smaller `list of strings` and after that `append` that `list` to one big `list of lists`. When I'm trying to insert small `list` to big `list` it insert the values from one list to another, but don't preserve a shape `list in list` but instead make it `string in list`. How could I preserve the first one, so when I loop the big one, it will throwing small lists?

```cpp
//a.hpp

    std::list<std::string> Splitter(std::string str_to_splt, std::string delimeter) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    std:: string token;
    std::list<std::string> delimeted_data;
    while ((pos = str_to_splt.find(delimeter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = str_to_splt.substr(0, pos);
        delimeted_data.push_back(token);
        str_to_splt.erase(0, pos + delimeter.length());
    }
    return delimeted_data;
```

```cpp
// a.cpp
    readBuffer = regex_replace(readBuffer, regex("\\r"), ""); // get some string of data
    main_data_without_newlines = Splitter(readBuffer, "\n"); // split it to a list
    for (string v: main_data_without_newlines){
        servers = Splitter(v, ","); // split every string in list and output a new small list
        main_data_edited.insert(main_data_edited.end(), servers.begin(), servers.end()); // insert small list to big one -> inserted values are strings, not lists
    }
```

Comment: You need a `std::list<std::list<std::string>>`? I'll suggest giving your inner data `std::list<std::string>` a meaning fult name as a structure/class instead of using nested list.

Comment: so I should make list of structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` inserts each item of the iterated object (`servers`) in the target list. Each item is a `std::string`. Also you are inserting the items into a `std::list<std::string>`, which does not allow sublist items (since items *must* be strings). If you want a list of lists, you need to create one, e.g.

```cpp
std::list<std::list<std::string>> lists;
for (const auto &v: main_data_without_newlines) {
  lists.push_back(Splitter(v, ","));
}
```